# Post Method never being called in ApiController

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am not able to add a user to my database. After running the code I noticed that my Post method within the ApiController is never being called.

Here is my controller: ChatUserController

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using SignalRChat.Models;

namespace SignalRChat.Controllers
{
    public class ChatUserController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/chatuser
        public IEnumerable<ChatRoomUser> Get()
        {
            var user = UserRepository.GetChatRoomUsers();
            return user.ToList();
        }

        // GET api/chatuser/5
        public ChatRoomUser Get(int id)
        {
            return UserRepository.GetChatRoomUsers().FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == id);
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage Post(ChatRoomUser user)
        {
            UserRepository.AddUser(user);
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, user);
            var uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = user.UserId });
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
            return response;
        }

        // PUT api/chatuser/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/chatuser/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my javascript file that is located in a folder within the root of the Project:
UserViewModel.js

```
/// <reference path="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js" />

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new user(), document.getElementById('createNode'));
});

function user(username,roomid,roomname) {
    var self = this;
    self.UserName = username;
    self.RoomId = roomid;
    self.RoomName = roomname;

    self.addUser = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/chatuser/",
            type: "post",
            data: ko.toJSON(this),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(result) {

            }
        });
    };
}
```

Here is my view: Users.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Users";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/MyJS/UserViewModel.js"></script>

<h2>Users</h2>

<div id="createNode">@Html.Partial("CreateUser")</div>
```

Here is my partial View: CreateUser.cshtml

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>UserName</th>
        <td> <input type="text" data-bind="user: UserName"/></td>

        <th>RoomId</th>
        <td> <input type="number" data-bind="user: RoomId" /></td>

        <th>RoomName</th>
        <td> <input type="text" data-bind="user: RoomName" /></td>
    </tr>


</table>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="btnAddUser" value="Add User" data-bind="click: addUser" />
```

I have been trying to figure this out but I feel like it has something to do with the javascript file because that is where the Post method should be getting called. Right?

All help is much appreciated.

EDIT:

My WebAPI controller is located here

[image]

I do not have a WebAPI.config file but i have a web.config file? So sounds like that is an issue?

Here is the Web.config file that is selected in my picture:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="SignalRChat" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you has a look with Firebug's Network tab or Fiddler or some other network traffic tool to see what (if anything) is being posted?

Comment: I just installed Fiddler and It is getting a 404 error. HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: What should the AJAX URL be?

Comment: Can you hit the GET action or is that returning a 404 as well?

Comment: The GET action returns a 404 error as well

Answer (score 3):

Update -

Since you are getting a 404 with your get method as well.  I'm guessing that your routing is wrong.  Post your WebApiConfig.cs file and your directory structure where your api controller is.

Original answer -

It's because you're passing in (this) instead of (self) which is where you binded all of your data to.

Change -

```
data: ko.toJSON(this)
```

to -

```
data: ko.toJSON(self)
```

Comment: I tried it but it is still not work. Is there any way to post my entire solution on stackoverflow?

Comment: I think either your routing is wrong or your api controller is in the wrong spot.  I just updated my response. List out your WebApiConfig and your directory.

Comment: That's your issue.  You need a WebApiConfig file to tell the server how to handle the requests to that URL.  Create a new WebApi project is Visual Studio to see how the layout is.  When you create a new porject, you'll also see that the API controllers are in a separate api directory under controllers.

Comment: Okay, i just created a brand new project that is API and it still did not work. Is there any chance you would be willing to look at my solution?